# How do I find and activate missing fonts in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts

In Microsoft Excel 2007: I cannot get `Arial Regular`. In TurboTax 2010, I cannot open the program because of missing Arial and Verdana fonts.  I can see some of them in `C:\Windows\Fonts`.

I can activate some of them by opening and closing the font file.  But how do I know if all the fonts are available?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is open

> Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Fonts > Font settings.

Click **Restore default font settings**.

Thats it

Comment: This doesn't seem to have fixed the issue on Windows 7. Verdana is still missing.

Comment: This doesn't fix my Windows 7 which has bold and italic fonts everywhere. Tahoma has only bold font installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, computer  Compaq Presario (by HP), Windows 7 Home Premium, missing Verdana Regular.  Restore Default font settings didn't work, because it was not the "setting" but the font that was missing.

Went to the tree using winsx, found the folder of Verdana files, and with right click, hit Install. I also do not know why these files are missing from the installation of windows 7,

Answer (score 1):

I was missing some fonts too, although my comptuer is a Lenovo.

Installing the [European Union Expansion Font Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16083) fixed the issue though!

Answer (score 0):

found his answer on another site and it worked
Missing Fonts on New 2010 HP Computers Windows 7.Options 
Mark as NewBookmarkSubscribeSubscribe to RSS FeedHighlightPrintReport Inappropriate Content....12-16-2010 01:51 PM

I do setup on a number of computers and have noticed lately that some HP computers were displaying onscreen text in italics. I went through a number of support forums, tried adjusting fonts in Internet Explorer and on the desktop to no avail. I finally had a client that was unable to to start a new copy of Turbotax because of missing fonts. Lo and behold, the installation of Windows 7 on his HP computer was missing Arial Regular, Verdana Regular and Verdana Bold. Went into the C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-font-tru​etype-arial_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_c​e7861d6c70c1a93 FOLDER and the C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-font-tru​etype-verdana_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none​_1a6e14c718deeae7 FOLDER to retrieve the missing fonts. Can a representative from HP explain that one?
....

Comment: Thank you Cheryl.  I got my known missing fonts so that TurboTax works, like your client.  But I am concerned that i may have other fonts "in limbo".  That is, font files are on my hard drive, but applications such as MSWord or MSExcel cannot "see" them.  Any further thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know what caused the problem in Windows7; but I also discovered that many of my fonts were longer being recognized (ala TurboTax) or replaced with italics.

Contacting HP support didn't help; they always recommend a complete Windows restore when they can't figure it out.

I copied the "Fonts" file from the Windows folder in another computer over our network. Dragging and dropping the missing fonts into my Fonts file opened the install font dialog. Installed and everything worked